# Using Electron based app as a web server

Tags: cross-platform, remote-access, electron, remote-server

I'm developing a cross-platform application (Windows/Linux/macOS), which:

1. Should be able to run locally as a desktop application
2. Should be able to run on a remote machine, preferably with the same UI as on local.

So far [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) looks good enough for the first bullet.

The question is about the second one. I'd like to reuse both the logic and the UI from the local scenario for the remote scenario. In other words, I'd like to use Electron based application as a web server and connect to it via browser.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a remote web server without Electron, just with Node.js, and deliver a web page like a PHP server for example.

But if you want to deliver a complete remote UI and manage the window remotely, that's VERY complicated to do... That needs to configure a lot of things and manage connections between client and server, using asynchronous keyboard & mouse and encryption to secure the communications.

Answer (score 0):

You want a hybrid app I think, like a few of them that out out there (i.e. Slack). Generally there's a web app plus an Electron client version with some shared UI code but it's not Electron all around. The main point of electron is to be a local web server acting as a desktop app. You could certainly keep it all node though.